# Combination-Counting problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many different ways can 200 coins be distributed among 10 people so that:

1)everyone gets 0, or more, coins?

2)everyone gets 5, or more, coins?

I know how to do question it they have an exact requirement like if they each need a certain amount. However, when it comes to 0 or more I don't know how to approach the question can someone teach me the way?
Thank you.

Comment: The correct search term here is [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  Also, if ten people get 5 or more coins each., that would require at least 50 coins to cover the minimums for everyone... which is more than 40 so...

Comment: Sorry man I got the question wrong is there a way of how to tackle the question now?

Comment: Again, I refer you to the link I gave.  It very clearly outlines how to approach problems like these and gives proofs for the formulas.  The only thing remaining for the second problem is to recognize that to distribute $200$ coins to $10$ people where each gets at least five, you can first give everyone five coins and then the question becomes how many ways you can distribute the remaining $150$ coins among $10$ people such that they each get $0$ or more.

Comment: Alright, Thankyou man it means a lot.